# Razor - First Element of ForEach or ForEach Loop only once

Tags: c#, loops, razor, foreach

I would like this ForEach to return h3 to me only once, instead of three which is the length of the array. How can I do? Thanks to those who will answer

```
 @foreach (var winelistObj in Model.winetype.Where(s => s.name == Request.Query["wine"]))
{
 <h3 class="text-uppercase font-logo text-regular letter-spacing-200">@winelistObj.name</h3>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to concat all matching wines comma separated, then use `string.Join`:

```
@{ string matchingWines = string.Join(",", Model.winetype.Where(s => s.name == Request.Query["wine"]).Select(w=> w.name)); }
<h3 class="text-uppercase font-logo text-regular letter-spacing-200">@matchingWines</h3>
```

You could add an `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(matchingWines)) { ... }` so that you don't render the `h3` if there was no matching wine or render a different message.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var winelistObj in Model.winetype.Where(s => s.name == Request.Query["wine"]).FirstOrDefault())
{
 <h3 class="text-uppercase font-logo text-regular letter-spacing-200">@winelistObj.name</h3>
}
```

This should give you the first result of the array.